# Get coordinates to generate bounding box from OpenCV output image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am using the OpenCV GrabCut algorithm as outlined [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html#grabcut) to extract the foreground in an image.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (50,50,450,290)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

Now I can save this image obtained by using `cv.imwrite('filename', img)` and the output image contains the foreground only, with the background being blacked out.

I wanted to get coordinates of the bounding box for the foreground as `(LowerXcoordinate, LowerYcoordinate)` and `(UpperXcoordinate, UpperYcoordinate)`.

One way I can imagine is to consider the image as a 2D matrix of pixels, to get the upper Y-coordinate, start from row 1 and row-by-row check if the color value of all pixels is black. The first row with a non-black pixel will be where the foreground starts. Similarly, starting from the last row of the and working the way up, I could get the lower Y-coordinate. And just repeat the procedure with columns to get X-coordinates.

Right now the only naive way I know of is by manually writing loops to check this.

Is there some simpler method using library functions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed much easier than that! Simply [find the contours of your mask (docs)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) and then [find the bounding rectangle (docs)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366) of the contour.

```py
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(contour) for contour in contours]
```

Note here that the bounding boxes will be represented by the four items `(x, y, w, h)`, where `x, y` is the top left corner, and `w, h` are the width and height respectively. There will be a bounding box for each blob in the mask.

Also, important (annoying) note. Older versions of OpenCV (I believe pre-3.0) had *two* return values from `findContours()`; just the contours and the hierarchy. Then in OpenCV 3 this was changed and returned three values: the input image, contours, and hierarchy. In OpenCV 4 this was changed back to the two. So remove that first `_` if you're not using OpenCV 3.